# If $\nabla f(x) = 0$ on a set $S$, is $f$ necessarily constant on $S$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, constants

If $\nabla f(x) = 0$ on a set $S$, is $f$ necessarily constant on $S$?

I know it is true when $S$ is open convex, or open connected, but what about any arbitrary $S$?

Comment: Think about the problem when dealing with one variable function.

Answer (score 5):

if $S$ is disconnected, give $f$ a different constant value on each component of $S$ and we see that the conjecture is false.

Comment: Exactly.. So, this cannot be true on a given $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually so simple, I didn't think about this.

Comment: It's worth remembering that connectedness is equivalent to there being no non-constant continuous integer-valued functions on the set. (see eg my book "proof patterns")

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you define $S$ to be the disconnected set above and the height of the line above a horizontal line to be the value of $f(x)$, you can see how it is false.

This can be extended to higher dimensions in an analogous way.

Comment: Your example (though good in spirit) doesn't work. Your choice of $S$ doesn't have accumulation points so limits don't make sense.

Comment: Oh yeah, woops. How about that?